# JLabel won't display image

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I'm creating a Tic-Tac-Toe game using Java. Right now, I have it so when you click on a button, that `JButton` will be removed from the `JPanel`, a `JLabel` containing either an X or O image will be added, and the `JPanel` will be repainted. However, when I click on the button, the image won't display, but the button dissapears.

Creation of the button and the `JLabel`/`Image`:

```
package tictactoe;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class TicTacToe implements ActionListener
{
private JFrame holder = new JFrame();
private GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(3,3);
private FlowLayout panel = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER);
private JPanel p11, p12, p13, p21, p22, p23, p31, p32, p33;
private JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9;
private ImageIcon iconX = new ImageIcon("iconX.png");
private JLabel xLabel = new JLabel(iconX);
private ImageIcon iconO = new ImageIcon("iconO.png");
private JLabel oLabel = new JLabel(iconO);
private int turn;
private char s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9;

public TicTacToe()
{
    paint();
}

private void paint()
{
    holder.setLayout(layout);
    holder.setSize(300,300);

    b1 = new JButton("1");
    p11 = new JPanel();
    p11.setLayout(panel);
    p11.add(b1);
    holder.add(p11);

    //Same block of code for the next 8 buttons/panels inserted here

    holder.setVisible(true);

    b1.addActionListener(this);
    //Other action listeners inserted here

}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (e.getSource() == b1)
    {
        ++turn;
        p11.remove(b1);
        if (turn % 2 == 1) { s1 = 'x'; p11.add(xLabel); }
        else if (turn % 2 == 0) { s1 = 'o'; p11.add(oLabel); }
        p11.repaint();
    }
    //Other action events inserted here
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    TicTacToe game = new TicTacToe();
}
}
```

[image: Picture of the problem]

Answer (score 3):

Try calling `revalidate();` then `repaint();` on your `JPanel`s instance like this:

```
        p11.revalidate();
        p11.repaint();
```

When a `Component` is added or removed it is necessary to call `revalidate()` this call is an instruction to tell the `LayoutManager` to reset based on the new `Component` list. `revalidate()` will trigger a call to `repaint()` what the component thinks are 'dirty regions.' Obviously not all of the regions on your `JPanel` are considered dirty by the `RepaintManager`.

`repaint()` is used to tell a component to repaint itself. It is often the case that you need to call this in order to cleanup conditions such as yours.

Comment: It might be useful if you also explain why this approach may work.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (e.getSource() == b1) {
                ++turn;
                p11.remove(b1);
                if (turn % 2 == 1) { s1 = 'x'; p11.add(new JLabel(iconX)); }
                else { s1 = 'o'; p11.add(new JLabel(iconO)); }
                //p11.revalidate();
                //p11.repaint();
            }
            **Other action events inserted here
        }
    });
}
```

The **invokeLater** construction is a bit much syntax, but lets the event handling thread handle the button click, and *later* do the changes. Otherwise you cannot rely on the immediate repainting and the gui becomes less responsive. *(The Runnable object can only access **final** variables from outside, that is: variables which no longer are assigned to.)*

Components like `JLabel` have a single field for their parent component. Hence one cannot reuse one component. Hence the `new JLabel()`.

About repainting; always first try it without triggering it yourself.